# How get Exec field from desktop file

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, gtk, gio

how extract Exec field from .desktop file. Gio can help me?

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import os
from gi.repository import Gio

launcher = Gio.DesktopAppInfo.new_from_filename('/usr/share/applications/chromium.desktop')
# how get Exec field from desktop file
# cat /usr/share/applications/chromium.desktop | grep ^Exec

#retval = launcher.launch_uris()
```

i totally newbie..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> print launcher.get_commandline()